# How do I Left align a form inside a Bootstrap well

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Below is my code for the entire container that contains a row with a "span5 well" and a "span6".

If I make the 2nd a "span7", although they do add up to 12, the WELL causes the 2nd span to shift to next row. Even at desktop resolution. The Form only has a few inputs and I did not use text field labels, I used placeholders to take up less space. there are a few parts to this question.

How can I left align the form inside the well? right now it wants to go right, and also hangs off the well a bit.

Should I even use the "well" to hold the form, or should I just put a border around the "span5" and make the background color grey to resemble the "well" background ?

here is the code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span5 well" style="border-radius:10px">
            <h3 style="text-align:center">Let us know how we can help</h3>
            <hr>
            <div><%= render "customers/form"%></div>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            <div>
                <%= image_tag 'Sprinkler2.png' %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with your code?

Comment: well adds padding... spanX is supposed to make a thing a fixed size... you should probably use them separately. I'd recommend making another div inside the span5 that is the well

Comment: I decided to skip the well altogether, but there must still be a default "padding-left" on a form, and its causing the form to hang to the right of the border, any suggestions ?